# off blue lines in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Suddenly after pressing mistakenly some keys my visual studio coding editior is showing blue lines how could i turn it off?Example

[image]

Comment: that is to show you the indent of the code lines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>

[image]